# Java: String to Boolean

Tags: java, boolean, objectinputstream

I have to read a `String` from a field and then convert it to a `Boolean`.
I've tried this:

```
ObjectInputStream nm;
nm = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("buscamines.txt"));
String s = nm.readLine();
Boolean bool = Boolean.valueOf(s);
```

But it's not working, when I print the string `s`, it is correct but the `Boolean` value is always `false`.

Is there any other way to convert a `String` to `Boolean`?

Comment: You wrote in your question: _when I print the String s, it is correct_ Perhaps `s` contains leading (or trailing) spaces? Perhaps it contains non-printing characters? I presume that the value of `s` is **true**. I suggest you print the length of `s` and see whether it is 4.

Answer (score 3):

According to Java's [`Boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) documentation:

> `public static Boolean valueOf(String s)`
>   Returns a `Boolean` with a value represented by the specified string. The `Boolean` returned represents a true value if the string argument is not `null` and is equal, ignoring case, to the string `"true"`.

So, it means that:

```
System.out.print(Boolean.valueOf("true")); // -> true
System.out.print(Boolean.valueOf("TRUE")); // -> true
System.out.print(Boolean.valueOf("tRuE")); // -> true
System.out.print(Boolean.valueOf("false")); // -> false
System.out.print(Boolean.valueOf("anything else")); // -> false
System.out.print(Boolean.valueOf("TRUE ")); // -> false
```

Comment: What `Boolean` value is obtained for the string "TRUE " (i.e. with a trailing space) ?

Comment: @Abra `System.out.print(Boolean.valueOf("TRUE "));` will return `false`.