# Why is Boolean.valueOf(String) returning false when given neither true or false but a random String?

Tags: java, exception, boolean, try-catch

When using the method Boolean.valueOf(String) the return value is false when given any String besides "true". This try block neverseems to fail even if it should?

```
boolean a;

String b = "randomTextThatsNotTrueOrFalse";

try{
a= Boolean.valueOf(b);
} 
catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {

 LOG.error(b  + "is invalid. Only true or false are possible  Options.");

}
```

Comment: [Did you read its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62235771/61158

Comment: The Boolean returned represents a true value if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true". Plus, the try catch block is checking for, ```IllegalArgumentException``` which is never the case here!. The method is expecting a string, and you are giving it a string, thus the exception is not triggered. You are misusing the try catch block. To check, just try to print out the result of b, at the end, and you would see that the method is correctly working regardless of the try-catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the spec (and, as expected, the source code of the OpenJDK implementation follows this spec), `"true"` (with any casing) is parsed as `true`, and all other strings are parsed as `false`:

> ```java
>    * Returns a {@code Boolean} with a value represented by the
>    * specified string.  The {@code Boolean} returned represents a
>    * true value if the string argument is not {@code null}
>    * and is equal, ignoring case, to the string {@code "true"}.
>    * Otherwise, a false value is returned, including for a null
>    * argument.
> ```

Reading javadoc is important; you should make a habit of it.

If you want a method that returns `true` if passed `"true"`, `false` if passed `"false"`, and throws an IAEx otherwise, you'd have to write it yourself. It's about 80 characters worth of code.